# Which site do I ask about problems with Google Chrome?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a problem in Google Chrome where any save dialog appears and quickly disappears, and I have to bring it in front using Task Manager every time. I am not sure where to ask for its solution.

Comment: This is a good place to "ask where to ask".

Comment: That question might be a good fit for [superuser](http://superuser.com)?

Comment: In fact, we have a whole tag for that kind of question on Meta: [site-recommendation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)

Comment: oh..my bad i wasn't aware of that tag, thanx for informing.

Comment: When in doubt the rule of thumb is to address Super User and let them migrate it to a more appropriate site, if required. It's like the catchall Q/A site on StackExchange.

Comment: No it's not @EvanCarroll. And that is terrible advice. And to [try and edit that into an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18907) is pretty poor form.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for rejecting that edit. I was going to, but I didn't get time.

Comment: @gparyani that's not true.  Mods can migrate anywhere.  It's just regular users than can only migrate to one of the 5 sites identified sites

Comment: @psubsee2003 But moderators don't always migrate, if they think that a user is posting questions that are off-topic.

Comment: @gparyani never said they would migrate on request, just that they can so the comment was somewhat confusing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example question is best suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com):

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's 100% free, no registration required.