# Which is the place to ask for Firefox and Chrome issues?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am having issues in both Firefox and Chrome browser on Windows 10. When you browse to www.google.com it just render something like this (I took that img from Google Image not an actual screenshot) [image]

But that's not the point, the point is, where can I ask this? is not code related, just installed software malfunctioning due some bad configuration, virus, etc

Comment: [su] is the site you’re looking for

Comment: and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201674/which-site-do-i-ask-about-problems-with-google-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Super User, ok, got it, thanks

Comment: disable all extensions or run it in incognito mode may solve your problem. anyway [su] is the place to ask